# Including php in div boxes changing their position

Tags: php, html, css

Alright, so basically I aligned 9  boxes in three rows vertically and horizontally, and used css to position them. Everything went fine and worked, until I included a php command to access a mysql database and echo certain rows inside the divs. The first box maintained it's position, however the second was too far to the right and higher than I originally set it to be, the 3rd one was all the way off the screen, you had to scroll to see it. I've attempted to fix this through positioning in html (and deleting the css commands), however this only works for chrome. In firefox the boxes seem to ignore the command and start at the left top corner.

the  codes with the php inside look like this:

```
<div id= "box1"> <div style="position: absolute;background-color:#fff;width:250px;height:120px;border:0px;">

<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("testtest") or die(mysql_error());

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 0, 1;");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo '<div style="font-weight: bold;">';
echo $row["Title"];
echo '</div>';
echo '<div style="font-weight: normal;">';
echo $row["Offer"];
echo '</div>';
}
?>
</div>
```

and the css codes look like this (obviously different for each box, but you get the point)

```
# box1 {
margin-top: -140px;
margin-left: 830px;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help, I'm really stuck there and I can't seem to figure out why php would affect the positioning of a div..

Comment: i think your child div style affects the parent div...

Comment: With your present code it's difficult to understand what's appearing on your screen. You should either add screenshots, parsed HTML or a jsfiddle of this problem would give you much faster replies.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't post images yet because I don't have 10 rep power.. I'm not sure how a jsfiddle works, but when I figure it out, I'll post a link.. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to re-write your page markup. Using a negative margin is probably not the best idea, especially if the boxes are position:absolute; Instead you could set a parent container for your boxes, and position each box based on that.
Have you set the overflow of the boxes?

here is a [simple template](http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/fFdBs)...

With a bit of luck this will help solve your bug.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! This template looks helpful, I will try this

Answer (score 0):

Hum i don't know if your forgot to print here, but you have a div tag not closed.

Comment: Thanks for your time, however I can't seem to figure out which one I forgot to close..

Comment: <div id= "box1"> <div style="position: absolute;background-color:#fff;width:250px;height:120px;border:0px;">
the 2nd is not closed.

Comment: ahhh that was part of the problem, thanks a lot!! how do you add reputation here? ill try to give some to everyone who answered here

Comment: I don't know but it will be helpfull for me, thanks ;) i need reputation. Do you have a button or something like this to say that the response was helpfull ?